# Limit does not evaluate power function

Tags: limit, sympy

I am trying to take a relatively simple limit using sympy:

```
from sympy import *
f,k,b = symbols('f k b')
test = f**b - k**b
limit(test,k,f)
```

I am expecting 0, but I am getting:

```
>>> limit(test,k,f)
f**b - exp(b*log(f))
```

Mathematically this is correct (and zero), but why doesn't it evaluate to zero?

Note if I define:

```
from sympy import *
f,k,b = symbols('f k b')
test = exp(b*log(f)) - exp(b*log(k))
limit(test,k,f)
```

then I do get zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be incorrect to assert the limit is zero in general. Consider the following computation in Python console:

```
>>> (-1)**(1/2)
(6.123233995736766e-17+1j)
>>> (-1 - 1e-15j)**(1/2)
(5.053215498074303e-16-1j)
```

Because of the branch cut of complex square root along the negative real axis, the two extremely close values of the base produce quite different results (the difference is about 2j).

The limit is indeed zero if we stick to positive base and real exponents

```
from sympy import *
k = symbols('k')
f = symbols('f', positive=True)
b = symbols('b', real=True)
test = f**b - k**b
limit(test,k,f)   # returns 0
```

Comment: Happy to accept the answer as it solves my problem. Thanks for taking the time to answer. I am a little unsure about the explanation though. In my second example, when I write test = exp(blog(f)) - exp(blog(k)) , sympy does evaluate the limit to zero. But the issue about branch cuts seems to apply here too. E.g. b=1/2, f=-1, and k=-1-I*eps where eps is real positive and approaches zero. Then, because of the branch cut of the logarithm, term1 = +I and term2->-I? So it seems the limit is not always zero (depending on the direction in the complex plane k approaches f), but sympy gives zero.

Comment: Yes, returning 0 for the limit of exp(b*log(f)) is an incorrect result in general, since the point at which limit is taken may be a branch cut point. Apparently, the algorithm SymPy uses for evaluation of limits is not fully aware of branch cut.

Comment: Note that `limit` computes the real limit (approaching from the right by default). Complex limits are not implemented.